# transforming a vector from cartesian to spherical and cylindrical co-ordinate system

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I know the formula(which i don't know how to copy here but it was in matrix form) for transforming a vector from cartesian system to spherical or cylindrical coordinate system.
But, I want to know its **derivation**.
I tried searching it on web but all i got was some jacobian formulas , that i have no idea about.

Comment: Where have you looked? Sometimes Wikipedia pages are not very good to learn the derivation of formulas, but the respective sources have some content. Maybe saying what is incomplete in what you found could help.

Comment: Do you understand at least the [two-dimensional](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/78/Polar_to_cartesian.svg/500px-Polar_to_cartesian.svg.png) case ? If so, can't you generalize ? It should be rather plain and straight-forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to derive this. It's maybe easiest to think about how to express the unit vectors in one coordinate system in terms of those of the other. I found many decent looking references when googling "vectors in spherical and cartesian coordinates", among them the following:
1)http://www.csupomona.edu/~ajm/materials/delsph.pdf

2)http://www.ie.itcr.ac.cr/acotoc/Maestria_en_Computacion/Sistemas_de_Comunicacion_II/Material/Biblio1/chapter%2002.pdf

3)http://www.physics.purdue.edu/~jones105/phys310/coordinates.pdf

In principle it's all already in the first picture in (1) here. However, working through (2) might be more helpful since it's a bit more explicit.

Comment: Thanks for your help.It is greatly appreciated.I think probably I was looking in the wrong direction for the sources or am a poor googler. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. If you need more references: This is a standard thing to study for physics or engineering undergrads. You can read about it in the respective textbooks, but especially "Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences" (by Boas, ~page 520 or so) or "Mathematical Methods for Physicists" (Arfken, Weber). In general, any book with "Mathematical Methods" in the title should be a good guess.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity (laziness?), let's look at the 2d case, switching from cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ to polar $(r,\theta)$.  The 3d cases you mentioned are completely similar, and working them out would be a good exercise.

Let $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ denote the velocity vectors of the curves $t\mapsto (x+t,y)$, respectively $t\mapsto (x,y+t)$ (there is actually a reason for this notation!).  So $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ are the usual basis vectors $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$.

Similarly, let $\partial_r$ and $\partial_\theta$ denote the velocity vectors of the curves of constant $\theta$, respectively constant $r$. Differentiating $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ with respect to $r$ and $\theta$, we get $$\partial_r =\cos(\theta)\partial_x + \sin(\theta)\partial_y$$
and
$$\partial_\theta = -r\sin(\theta)\partial_x + r\cos(\theta)\partial_y$$
For $r>0$ these form a basis for the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$, so away from the origin, any vector field $v:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be written $v=\alpha(r,\theta)\partial_r+\beta(r,\theta)\partial_\theta$.  We can also write $v=a(x,y)\partial_x+b(x,y)\partial_y$. A comparison gives
$$a=\cos(\theta)\alpha-r\sin(\theta)\beta\hskip.8in b=\sin(\theta)\alpha + r\cos(\theta)\beta.$$
You can solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ if you like!